2410 Monitor Powersave is... short lived
New system, just installed 24.04 and then upgraded to 24.10.
So if I use the Super-L keyboard combination, the screen blanks, locks, and monitors go into powersave. Nice, exactly as expected.
Then... about 8 seconds later, the monitors come back on. Screen is still blank, and moving the mouse or typing something on the keyboard returns the login prompt to visibility, so there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with that.
Same thing happens on logout- so don't think there is a background app that is sending something the system would construe as HID activity.
I don't know what to even look for in syslog et al, there are a lot of events surrounding a logout and login, none of which appear suspicious, and nothing concerning power events.
Choosing a wayland or xorg session doesn't seem to matter, either.
Help?
